# How to read character type data as data frame in R

Tags: xml, r

I want to scrape some data from a website. But I got a problem that the type of the data I scrape is character. I want to convert it to data frame, just the same as what you can see from this website.

**http://app.finance.ifeng.com/hq/stock_daily.php?code=sh600030**

```
require(RCurl)
require(rjson)
library(stringr)   
library(XML)

url="http://app.finance.ifeng.com/hq/stock_daily.php?code=sh600030"
SOURCE <-  getURL(url,encoding="UTF-8")
PARSED <- htmlParse(SOURCE)

k <- xpathSApply(PARSED, "//td",xmlValue)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `readHTMLTable`

```
url="http://app.finance.ifeng.com/hq/stock_daily.php?code=sh600030"
SOURCE <-  getURL(url,encoding="UTF-8")
DF <- readHTMLTable(SOURCE)[[1]]
```

But you should get the encoding of the chinese characters right. Dont know about this topit to be honest.

```
> head(DF)
        æ—¥æœŸ å¼€ç›˜ä»· æœ€é«˜ä»· æœ€ä½Žä»· æ”¶ç›˜ä»·       æˆäº¤é‡       æˆäº¤é¢ æ¶¨è·Œé¢ æ¶¨è·Œå¹…
1 N 2015-01-13     33.21     33.64     31.77     32.17 6243921<U+624B> 2034644<U+4E07>     -1.36    -4.06%
2 N 2015-01-12     34.70     35.38     33.23     33.53 6602672<U+624B> 2258232<U+4E07>     -1.43    -4.09%
3 N 2015-01-09     35.01     36.90     34.41     34.96 7636402<U+624B> 2714229<U+4E07>     -0.29    -0.82%
4 N 2015-01-08     36.40     36.70     34.68     35.25 6376268<U+624B> 2261846<U+4E07>     -0.90    -2.49%
5 N 2015-01-07     34.41     37.25     34.29     36.15 7315085<U+624B> 2638717<U+4E07>      1.44     4.15%
6   2015-01-06     33.80     35.58     33.56     34.71 6681193<U+624B> 2314937<U+4E07>      0.05     0.14%
```

Comment: But this contains an encoding parameter, it can not be used in the shiny.io server.